# Bash Printf Argument $1 vs "$1"

Tags: shell-script, printf

I have a shell script that prints the first argument passed to it in the command line. I was experimenting with `$1` and `"$1"`. Interestingly to me, when I pass "John Doe" I get different outputs.

**hw Version1**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Hello %s\n" $1
```

Result is the following. Seems like it loops through strings separated by space:

```
$ hw "John Doe"
Hello John
Hello Doe
```

**hw Version2**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Hello %s\n" "$1"
```

Result is:

```
$ hw "John Doe"
Hello John Doe
```

what is the difference between `$1` and `"$1"` when the argument in the command line is something like `"string1 string2 ... stringn"`?

Comment: Related: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: It's a duplicate all right but the question is well framed and formatted. IMO doesn't deserve a downvote

Comment: Thank you. I was surprised when it was downvoted.

Comment: What is not covered elsewhere is why Hello appears twice in Version 1. This is a specific action by the printf built-in: "The format is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments."